# Amplify/DynamoDB GSI filter (beginsWith) & sort GraphQL result

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, dynamodb-queries

I have the following table that I would like to index, filter with beginsWith and sort:

| id | geo | createdAt | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a7y8c | 2022-08-27T21:02:43.325Z | Lorem |
| 2 | b1x0b | 2022-08-26T12:32:43.464Z | Imsum |
| 3 | c1x0c | 2022-08-25T19:34:52.233Z | Dolor |
| 4 | c1x0d | 2022-08-24T21:12:43.323Z | Consetetur |
| 5 | c1x0e | 2022-08-23T11:43:53.723Z | sadipscing |
| 6 | d3f0f | 2022-08-22T16:34:53.245Z | takimata. |

My goal is to filter the field `geo` with `beginsWith=c1x` and sort the result by `createdAt`. Then get the result:

| id | geo | createdAt | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | **c1x**0c | 2022-08-25T19:34:52.233Z | Dolor |
| 4 | **c1x**0d | 2022-08-24T21:12:43.323Z | Consetetur |
| 5 | **c1x**0e | 2022-08-23T11:43:53.723Z | sadipscing |

My GraphQL schema looks like this:

```
type Item
  id: ID!
  content: String
  geo: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  status: Status @index(name: "listItemsByDate", queryField: "listItemsByDate", sortKeyFields: ["geo"])
}
```

With `sortKeyFields: ["createdAt", "geo"]` the sorting is correct and with `sortKeyFields: ["geo", "createdAt"]` the filtering works with startsWith.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the poblem?

Comment: Note that filters are the same in read unit cost as if you pulled the data to the client side and did the filtering there. It just saves the data going over the network. The disk reads and charges still happen. Are you sure you want to pull that much data?

Comment: I want to filter and then load the filtered data so I can work correctly with `limit`.

Comment: If filtering on geo then you’re literally searching the whole world. That’s going to work for you?

Comment: Exactly, that's why it's important to filter first and then load.

Comment: Filter is something you to do data after it’s loaded so I don’t understand what you’re saying.